# How to fasten a length of plastic rope which is just too short

Tags: home

If I have less rope than necessary to tie multiple knots fore safety, and I am trying too tie both the ends to an iron rod (similar to how I have depicted here with another rod in between or straight between two iron rods), the rope is about 20 centimeters longer than the distance between the two rods and hence leaves very little room for a comprehensive knot

[image]
[image]

This is just for drying clothes, so the weight that would be hung is not very high, but yes it needs to stand a wet jeans trouser probably and yes it would be better if I can reuse the rope in its entirety but not mandatory (this is just a temporary arrangement for the rainy season).

Comment: Are you... in jail?

Comment: :) thankfully not and I am not aware of a Jail where I could use internet so lavishly

Comment: How much stress/weight must the rope endure? Is it to hold something up?

Comment: @J.Musser just for drying clothes, so not very high, but yes it needs to stand a wet jeans probably. and yes it would be better if I can reuse the rope in its entirety but not mandatory

Comment: Do you have to remove the rope sometimes?

Comment: Just so that I clarify what it is for those curious (6 upvotes for the comment :P) this is something we made at home to ensure no one falls off the first floor

Comment: @J.Musser dont use bots look at the picture, I have shown what I have tried in the picture, generalisation is always dangerous

Comment: This question could use a good bit of improvement. How much rope do you have to tie a knot with? Is this going to be hanging permanently? What's wrong with the knot that you have tied now? How thick is the rope?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I don't understand is it so difficult to see from the question (the picture) as to how thick the rope is or how much I had to tie the knot, I have clearly mentioned just short, shown a picture what else needs to be done, I have also explained that this is temporary in comments, I shall move it to the question, but I get a feeling everyone's becoming paranoid about some set criteria and looking at the question without the images

Comment: @skv We're simply trying to help questions become more high quality. Relying on images isn't great because they may be unavailable in the future. Images can also be interpreted by people in slightly different ways, so adding a text description of the image is best

Comment: @ZachSaucier I am not questioning your intent, just the methodology and thanks for trying to improve the content here, however images, unlike external links are permanent and provide a clear cue.

Comment: In the pictures I'm seeing the ropes tied. So they're working? What's the problem?

Comment: They are not strong enough for wet clothes, as you can see the knots are basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really get a great knot with that little rope, but you *can* make it stronger. Here are some ideas:

- Melt it together. The easiest way is to use melted plastic from another source (a plastic bag perhaps) and spreading it all over the knot. The biggest problem with this: It won't come back off easily.
- Use a few safety pins on each knot, going through the rope on both sides of the knot. Not super strong, but it will handle drying wet laundry.
- Get a vicegrips and set it to squeeze tightly. Use it to squeeze the knot in place, and then just let it hang there until you wish to remove it. Much stronger, but you'll be shorter by two tools, if you even have these.
- Attach the rope lower down on the opposite wall, which will give you more slack and improve the chances of your ability to make a good knot.

Answer (score 3):

With plastic or nylon rope you could cut the fussed ends and separate a few inches of the rope on each end into the individual strands.

[image]

Most ropes will separate into 3 strands. Once you have the rope split on the ends just take the free strands and tie them to the bars or you can re twist and fuse them with the bar in the middle.

Doing this will reduce the strength of the rope considerably, but if you're just hanging laundry and you start with a rope similar to the one in your picture it should be more the strong enough to hold.